# Writing PySpark Df to csv when string columns contain commas?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The most information I can find on this relates to reading csv files when columns contain columns. I am having the reverse problem.

Because a few of my columns store free text (commas, bullets, etc.), whenever I write the dataframe to csv, the text is split across multiple columns.

```
+------+----------------------------------------+
| Col1 |                  Col2                  |
+------+----------------------------------------+
| 1123 | When there is, a comma, it is annoying |
| 1143 | When there isn't, it is great.         |
+------+----------------------------------------+
```

I have tried:

- Changing the delimiter
- Wrapping Col2 in double quotes (though I am not sure if it requires another option for this to work).

Sample Code:

Add Quotes

```
df = df.withColumn("Col2", F.concat(lit('"'), col("Col2"), lit('"')))
```

Write csv

```
df\
  .coalesce(1) \
  .write \
  .format("csv") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("sep","|") \
  .save("file.csv")
```

Comment: After you write the csv, where are you opening back to check if the format was correct?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the column with the quotes. The **option("quote", "\"")** does it for you.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("sep","|").option("quote", "\"").save("file.csv")
```

### Update

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1123, "\"When there is, a comma, it is annoying\""), (1143, "\"When there isn't, it is great.\"")]).toDF("Col1", "Col2")

df.show()
+----+----------------------------------------+
|Col1|Col2                                    |
+----+----------------------------------------+
|1123|"When there is, a comma, it is annoying"|
|1143|"When there isn't, it is great."        |
+----+----------------------------------------+

df.coalesce(1).write.option("quote", "\"").format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("sep","|").save("file.csv")

Result:

1123|"\"When there is, a comma, it is annoying\""
1143|"\"When there isn't, it is great.\""
```

Comment: does this work if there aren't quotes already around it?

Comment: sure, but the output will be double quoted.

Comment: it is still splitting the columns with commas into 2 separate ones

Comment: I have coded exactly what you described, with the expected result.

Comment: You start with Col2 already having quotes and \ around it. Is that something I need to add to the column?

Comment: Did it work for you in the end? Consider to give a vote if it was helpful...